# Good books on Green function?

Tags: reference-request

Are there some good books on Green function (or approximation Green function) and its application(mainly used in PDEs)? Any reply will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you make the question more specific? What level are you looking for? What do you want to know about Green's functions?

Comment: @Scott Morrison: I want to find the Green function for the generally linear constant coefficients wave equation or some strong coupled system of two wave type equations. And if I consider the non-constant coefficients case or nonlinear case, should I need to find the approximation Green function? My aim is to use Green function to estimate the solutions of corresponding PDEs. I'm not familiar with the theory of Green function used in PDEs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For wave equations, a classic book by Gerard Friedlander is ``The wave equation on
curved spacetime'', which describes the Hadamard parametrix method.
There is another nice recent book by Christian Baer called Linear wave equations
on Lorentzian manifolds.